# Not seeing any data in Table

Tags: android, xml, android-tablelayout

I'm having a problem seeing the data that I'm trying to fill my `TableLayout` with.. When I run the code it doesnt error out but the table does not get filled with data it just shows up blank and all that I can see is the header row that I define in the `xml file`.

I have looked at multiple examples and have messed around with some of the answers that are given there, like switching the params around of my rows ( I have yet to find a correct combination ) and I have changed what I have imported from the `view` to the `widget` and still nothing...

```
public void createTable(String xmlForTable) 
    throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
//public void createTable(){

    Integer i = 0;
    endPlacementTag = "nothing";
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_tires);

     lo = (TableLayout)  findViewById(R.id.tiresTable);

     TableRow headerRow = new TableRow(this);
     TableRow.LayoutParams hp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     headerRow.setLayoutParams(hp);

     tv = new TextView(this);
     tv.setText("Text Header");
     headerRow.addView(tv);
     lo.addView(headerRow);

     XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
     factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
     XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

     xpp.setInput(new StringReader (xmlForTable));
     int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

     TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        row.setLayoutParams(lp);

        rfid = new TextView(this);
        projectNumber = new TextView(this);
        inspectionLotNumber = new TextView(this);
        serialization = new TextView(this);
        spec = new TextView(this);
        sku = new TextView(this);
        materialNumber = new TextView(this);


     while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

        if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {

              System.out.println("Start document");

          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

              System.out.println("End document");

          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

              System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
              placementTag = xpp.getName();

          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {

              System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
              endPlacementTag = "End tag "+xpp.getName();

          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {

              System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
          }

           ....//filled with more if statements same as this one just different .equals

          if(placementTag.equals("MaterialNumber"))
              {
                  materialNumber.setText(xpp.getText());
                  materialNumber.setTextSize(10);                   
                  materialNumber.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                  //row.addView(materialNumber);
                  placementTag = "";

              }
              else if(endPlacementTag.equals("End tag Table")) 
              {

                  row.addView(rfid);
                  row.addView(projectNumber);
                  row.addView(inspectionLotNumber);
                  row.addView(serialization);
                  row.addView(spec);
                  row.addView(sku);
                  row.addView(materialNumber);

                  row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                  row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                  lo.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                  i++;
                  row.removeAllViews();
                  lo.removeAllViews();

              }

              }
          eventType = xpp.next();
          }
```

Here's my XML:

```
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#C0C0C0"    >

<!-- Once the column headers are known go back into the string.xml file and add them to elimiate warnings -->

<TableRow android:background="#C0C0C0" 

    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="NUM" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Project Number" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Inspection Lot Number" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Serialization" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_column="4"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Spec" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_column="5"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="SKU" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_column="6"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Material Number" />
</TableRow>

<ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >      

    <HorizontalScrollView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" >

<TableLayout android:id="@+id/tiresTable"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#C0C0C0"  >          
<TableRow>

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>     
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code like the following. because you are removing all the views after adding. and you are not re initializing the child views of row again.

```
    public void createTable(String xmlForTable) 
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    //public void createTable(){

        Integer i = 0;
        endPlacementTag = "nothing";
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_tires);

         lo = (TableLayout)  findViewById(R.id.tiresTable);

         TableRow headerRow = new TableRow(this);
         TableRow.LayoutParams hp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         headerRow.setLayoutParams(hp);

         tv = new TextView(this);
         tv.setText("Text Header");
         headerRow.addView(tv);
         lo.addView(headerRow);

         XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
         factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
         XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

         xpp.setInput(new StringReader (xmlForTable));
         int eventType = xpp.getEventType();


            TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);





         while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
               TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
                row.setLayoutParams(lp);
                rfid = new TextView(this);
                projectNumber = new TextView(this);
                inspectionLotNumber = new TextView(this);
                serialization = new TextView(this);
                spec = new TextView(this);
                sku = new TextView(this);
                materialNumber = new TextView(this);
            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {

                  System.out.println("Start document");

              } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                  System.out.println("End document");

              } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                  System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
                  placementTag = xpp.getName();

              } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {

                  System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
                  endPlacementTag = "End tag "+xpp.getName();

              } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {

                  System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
              }

               ....//filled with more if statements same as this one just different .equals

              if(placementTag.equals("MaterialNumber"))
                  {
                      materialNumber.setText(xpp.getText());
                      materialNumber.setTextSize(10);                   
                      materialNumber.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                      //row.addView(materialNumber);
                      placementTag = "";

                  }
                  else if(endPlacementTag.equals("End tag Table")) 
                  {

                      row.addView(rfid);
                      row.addView(projectNumber);
                      row.addView(inspectionLotNumber);
                      row.addView(serialization);
                      row.addView(spec);
                      row.addView(sku);
                      row.addView(materialNumber);

                      row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                      row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                      lo.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                      i++;

                  }

                  }
              eventType = xpp.next();
              }
```

Comment: If I remove those lines of code I get this error  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
`